# Android Dialog UI scrambles with keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am using a custom dialog with `EditTexts` and `Button`.
But it gets scrambled whenever the keyboard is popped up..

I have tried this to solve this

```
d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

And My dialog code is this:

```
           final Dialog d = new Dialog(NewOrderDetrails.this);

            d.setContentView(R.layout.accept_dialog);
            d.setTitle("Enter Details");

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
             lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

            Button dispatch,cal;

            System.out.println("Delivery Phone" + getIntent().getStringExtra("Cphne") );

            invoice=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.accept_invoice_no);
            bill=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.accept_bill_amount);
            discount=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.accept_discount);
            dispatch = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.accept_dispatch);
            payblebill=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.accept_pay_amount);
            etd=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.accept_etd);
            cal=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.accept_calculate);


            cal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


            }

            });


            d.show();
            d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

            dispatch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                }

            });
```

I tried everything  i could, but the problem is still there, And believe me it's annoying.. Please help.

Comment: can you give a screenshot ..?

Comment: And while you are editing in the screenshot, please add the layout XML or the code where you are building the dialog's content.

Comment: This is my screen after keyboard http://i.imgur.com/vj9z9pe.png?1 and this before keyboard   http://i.imgur.com/z5JO3Xd.png?1 And i have put the dialog code in my question edit

Comment: You need to post your layout XML. It is compressing the dialog content so that it will fit on screen while the keyboard in shown. What is the behaviour you would rather see? Please describe the behaviour you want when the keyboard is shown. Obviously your exisitng layout and the keyboard cannot be both completely shown at the same time. Your screen is not big enoug.